# Is this a cross-domain issue?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I have a jQuery .ajax() call that works fine in IE 7 and 8. It does not work in FF or Chrome. I thought it was a cross-domain issue (because it is trying to call across domains) but my co-worker says if it were a cross-domain problem it wouldn't work in *any* browsers. Am I correct? Can a cross-domain issue appear in some browsers and not in others? Kinda new to this stuff...thanks!

UPDATE: Here is my code, using a test xml (won't match the attributes I try to display, but I'm just trying to get a feel for what's wrong with my ajax call):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml",  //test xml
        dataType: "xml", 
        success: xmlParser,
        asynch: true
    });
});

function xmlParser(xml) {

   $(xml).find("Offer:lt(3)").each(function () {

        $("#offers").append('<img src="' + $(this).find("logophotoname").text() + '"/><h1>' + $(this).find("listTitle").text() + '</h1><p>' + $(this).find("keywords").text() + '</p>');

    });

}
```

Comment: You should really provide more specific information

Comment: All current releases of major versions have pretty solid cross-domain protection. If you'd like to actually describe your problem you might get more help...

Comment: If you show us what your ajax call actually looks like we can give you an answer.

Comment: There are some access control restrictions in Firefox [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control)

Comment: Yes, I realized it is a cross-domain issue. Adding a server-side proxy pass worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your co-worker is correct. It should not work in any browser. However in IE 8 Microsoft introduced another object similar to the XmlHttpRequest -> XDomainRequest but I don't think you are using that, else IE 7 would fail. [(more info here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The ajax function of jQuery can be used to make a cross-domain call using JSONP. It will then inject an script object in the DOM tree instead of using a XmlHttpRequest object which has cross-domain restrictions.

(This whole post is related to your explanation only, it will help if you post some code. Maybe there's an other reason why it works in IE 7/8)

Answer (score 0):

In theory you cannot make cross-domain calls, but if you really want to, there are 2 options:
1. have a server based proxy script
2. JSONP